# With Git get know if are there new updates on remote and how much bytes to download

Tags: git, git-fetch

When call `git fetch` it will download pack immediately.

But I need to prepend one step before - check for updates (get know if new update available) and if possible get list of commits which will be downloaded like `git log master...origin/master` before pack will be downloaded.

In other words I'd say: *fetch git history (log) without fetching big objects*.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible by using just git commands.  
Probably you can do something only if your remote git repository has something like web pages, so you will need to write a parser to check is there any new commits.

Comment: nonono, pls do not suggest to look up on webpages.

Comment: [GitLab API. Compare branches, tags or commits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits)  -- something like this non-git API can solve the problem. But I don't want to rely on it.

Comment: Another idea is to post `git log` output to neighbor branch *history*. For example this action can do CI system when any other branch updated. It will not take too much to get news from that branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Well, let's modify that: you can't, *yet*.  Git 2.16 introduced the concept of *missing objects* and *partial clone*, but the rest of Git is not really ready for this.  But there may be such a feature at some point.

Note that to make this work, you would have to literally receive (download) the commit objects themselves.  However, each commit object is pretty small in general; what takes space and time to download, in a big pack file, are the underlying blob objects, and sometimes trees, and (for big repositories with millions of tags) the list of references and their hash IDs.  This last is also addressed, at least in partially, in the latest Git, which supports new transfer protocol versions.

The obvious way to make this work today is to have the *sending* Git tell you what you want to know, but you [ruled this idea out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52180270/with-git-get-know-if-are-there-new-updates-on-remote-and-how-much-bytes-to-downl#comment91314125_52180270).  (Note that it does not have to be a *web page*, just an accessible service.  It's just that today, "accessible service" is usually interpreted as meaning "web page".)

Comment: thanks. I get know that after seeking over many web pages.. Your message is the last nail in coffin of my idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git ls-remote` to check if references on the remote have changed, and hence fetch/pull is needed.

You could use `git fetch --dry-run` to get some details

Comment: This still downloads objects. `--dry-run` applied only to updating refspecs.